# How to let ios UI elements keeps to be the "origninal" elements when the view is switch back?

Tags: ios, swift

I want the text view append some text when receiving data from internet

```
    self.appDelegate.client?.addHandler("main_handler",handler:{(message) in
        print("debug info")
        self.textLabel.text = (message.getText()!)
    })
```

I switched to another view and return back to this view using segue .The text "debug info" is printed and the self.textLabel is not nil when receving data,but nothing is shown on screen.

It seems the view on the screen is completely a new view ,and so is the textlabel.

How could I reuse the original elements in the view? It's better to keep all the contents changed by code.

some code:

when connect_button is clicked this code is called,and status lable is changed to be connected

```
Async.background{
    self.app.conn = Connection(host: "ip",
        port: 1000)

    self.app.conn?.open(self.user!.token!){(state) in
        switch state{
        case .CONNECT:
            self.status("connected")
        case .DISCONNECT:
            self.status("disconnected")
        }            
    }
```

when perform segue and leave this view and return back.

the status changed to be disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `handler` executed on a background thread? When you update your UI you should do that on the main thread. Try this:

```
self.appDelegate.client?.addHandler("main_handler",handler:{(message) in
    print("debug info")

    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        self.textLabel.text = (message.getText()!)
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried this,still the same.When the view is swiched back,the text content is changed to blank,it seems the view is recreated.